# How to catch a Timeout Error with Redux-Observable + RxJS + Axios set-up?

Tags: rxjs, axios, redux-observable

Using Redux-Observable + RxJS + Axios the error returned when a call times out doesn't include any status code, etc. The whole error response in its entirety is `[TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred]`. How do I catch an error with that response in order to show a notification? The epic for this is below:

```
const fetchUserEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_USER'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(axios.get(`/user/`)).pipe(
        timeout(5000),
        map(response => ({
          type: 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS',
          data: response.data
        })),
        catchError(error =>
          of({
            type: 'FETCH_USER_ERROR',
            error
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: If it times out because of `timeout(5000)` there can't be any response (that's why timed out).

Comment: I get that but I thought Axios or RxJs would send back an object with a timeout status code etc so it' s possible to catch it easily? If not, I have to check if the error message includes the word 'timeout' and if it does display the timeout graphic, for example

Comment: It's RxJS that makes the timeout. This is completely unrelated to Axios.

Comment: Ok thanks. That helps to know that much

Answer (score 0):

The `error` object that is passed into the `catchError` handler has two string attributes: `message`, and `name`.

The whole object basically looks like this:

```js
{
    message: 'Timeout has occurred',
    name: 'TimeoutError'
}
```

See [TimeoutError.ts implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/860fc34a1d1a5e030c3338936fac9eefdb5d6974/src/internal/util/TimeoutError.ts#L9) for reference.

Hence to handle the rxjs timeout distinctly you could check:

```js
.catchError(error => {
    if (error.name === 'TimeoutError') {
        // handle rxjs timeout
    }
    ...
})
```

(At least that's what I am doing for a very similar use case as you have.)